# I want to animate the raster plot of 96 channels at each time point

Tags: matlab, animation, raster

So I have a binary matrix, 96x4000 where 96 represents the 96 electrodes I record from, and 4000 are time points, i.e. 4000ms. Each 1 represents one spike from that neuron.

What I now want to do, is plot the rasters of these channels in time. Each time point must show the spikes that happen in all 96 channels. Let's say that in the first time point, only 11 channels spike. So the line must appear only in 11 rows.

Now I want to plot all 96 rows at the same time, at each time point (animated).

I've gotten up to here -

https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/EmptyFrailHalibut

But I still get these big lines -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3mss.jpg

This is my current code -

```
figure
v = VideoWriter('testRaster')
open(v);
hold on
ylim([1 100])
xlim([-1 3])
for i = 1:4000
valIdx = [find(spikeTrains(:,i)==1)]';
if ~isempty(valIdx)
line([t(i)/1000 t(i)/1000],[[valIdx]' (spikeTrains(valIdx,i).*[valIdx]')+1],'Color','k')
drawnow
writeVideo(v, getframe(gcf));
end
end
close(v)
```

I'd be very grateful if someone could help me out! Thanks!

Comment: I tried your code and it worked as expected. I had to define t = -1000:3000. You didn't show the definition of t in your code above. Could this be where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The "big lines" may just be cases where all neurons are firing together.  Because you are creating a short vertical line for each neuron, they stack up and connect together visually.  One option is to shorten vertical distance (height) used for each electron from 1 to 0.5. For example, instead of the first electron going from [1 2], have it go from [1.2, 1.8].

Another option, that I prefer, is to use the `marker` option, and create your plots as points (one per neuron), with one point per electron instead of one short vertical line.  The interleaving white space may provide a more natural, visual gap.

You can also vectorize your code, instead of using `find`, since you are already dealing with binary data.  To do this, create a vector of y positions, corresponding to where each channels should be drawn on the vertical axis, and index into it with the spikes at that time. The same goes for your `t`.

Here's one way to do it, where I am simulating values for `spikeTrains` and `t_s` (your `t`).

```
clear all; close all;
figure;
v = VideoWriter('testRaster');
numChannels = 96;
spikeTrains = (randi(2,numChannels,4000)-1)&1;  %make it logical matrix
channels = 1:numChannels;
T_ms = 4000;
t_s = repmat(1:T_ms,numChannels,1)/1000;
open(v);
hold on;
ylim([1 100]);
xlim([-1 3]);
for k = 1:T_ms
    line(t_s(spikeTrains(:,k),k),channels(spikeTrains(:,k)),'Color','k',...
             'marker','.','linestyle','none');
    drawnow();
    writeVideo(v, getframe(gcf));
end
close(v)
```

If your `spikeTrains` are numerical (type double) 1's and 0's, then you may need to translate them to logical 1's and 0's.  I did this with the `&` above, but there are other ways you can do this

- `spikeTrains = spikeTrains==1; % transform numerical matrix to logical`
- `spikeTrains = spikeTrains&1;  % another way to do it`

This is not required for some of the earlier versions of MATLAB; just something to watch out for.